# What is the big-o notation for this algorithm?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

What will be the big-o notation for the algorithm that consist of multiplication of N in the loop.

```
void testing(int n) {
    for(int i =0; i<n;i++) {
        n=n*2;
        System.out.println("hi"+n);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `n` starts zero or negative, it will end immediately; that's O(1). If `n` starts positive, it will run until `n` overflows, so I guess ... that's a slower O(1).

Comment: This runs for infinity, given we assume that integers can be arbitrary large, and `n > 0`. So the concept of time complexity does not exist here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do we assume that integers can be arbitrarily large? It will actually overflow pretty quickly.

Comment: @khelwood: well evidently it all depends on certain assumptions. For example if one would use `BigInteger`s, then addition/subtraction/multiplications do not run in *O(1)* here. But if we consider ints to have a fixed size, a large amount of programs would, strictly speaking, run in *O(1)*. Since for example an array in Java contains a field with its length, and hence it is limited in size, and thus summing an array can only sum at most for example 2^64 items, and thus runs constant.

Comment: @user2478398 it is not for assignment, just for my curiosity. As i see that if inside the loop is n=n/2, it is o(log n) as it makes the step lesser every time it runs. So how if it is multiplication which will increase the n every time the loop runs.

Comment: @khelwood: usually the idea is however that if you analyze time complexity, you assume certain things that are, strictly speaking, not true. For example a machine with a maximum amount of memory (thus all machines) can do in fact loop detection. We can simply make a copy of all memory and CPU and disk states and thus check if that happens again.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I see what you mean. But you can also have an algorithm that requires and uses overflow in order to work, and then assuming that the integer will not overflow doesn't make much sense. But I agree, _if_ you were to assume no overflow, it's infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to be as rigorous as possible for my answer.

**EDIT** : forgot to say, we assume every operation like comparison, assignment and multiplication have complexity of **O(1)**

In short, this algorithm does not terminate in most of the cases, so complexity is not defined for it. 
Complexity is some kind of a upper bound for the cost **C** of an algorithm, stating **O(n)** complexity means **C <= k x n, k > 0**. Non terminating algorithm has a cost which is infinite, and **inf > inf** is undefined.

Then, let's look at why your algorithm is non-terminating :

each iteration, we continue if **i < n**. Yet, each iteration *n* is multiplied by **2**. We can see a relation between the value of **i** and *n* when checking for the condition of the loop : **n = n0x2^i**, with **n0** being the initial value of **n**. 
Therefore, your algorithm will only be terminating when *n0 <= 0*, and when this case occurs, it will not enter the loop once.

Comment: In what case does this not terminate?  Are you assuming no integer overflow for the purpose of time complexity?

Comment: @Nexevis if **n0 > 0**, this does not terminate, as **i < n0x2^i** will never be verified. When doing an **algorithmic** analysis, one usually supposes the program running on a turing machine -like computer, meaning it has infinite memory and infinite number size capability. That said, if you want to take in account a fixed bit integer size, and consider overflow as a normal behavior, then complexity analysis becomes quite complicated, because you potentially have cases where the leftover of the overflow of **n** is still greater than **i**.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code in my IDE and I found that it is an infinite loop.
Algorithm complexity is only defined for algorithms, which by (the most often accepted) definition must terminate. When a program doesn't terminate, it is not an algorithm. So it has no "algorithmic time complexity".

Comment: It's not an infinite loop. It will end when `n` overflows.

Comment: What did you use for `n`?  It does terminate in my IDE with `n=1` once the `int` overflowed.

Comment: try it for n = 10

Comment: @Sanjeev Sharma Just did, it does not loop infinitely with `n=10` for me, it terminates once the value is `-1610612736`

Comment: @khledwood I said it _terminates_ in my code?  We literally agree.

Comment: @Nexevis Quite right. Misread your comment.

Comment: so, should we conclude that it does not even depend on the value of n as every time it is terminating as soon as n overflows?

Comment: Yeah seems that way when n >= 1 at least.

Comment: It will overflow slightly faster for larger `n`.